# How can I output a HTML form to a local excel spreadsheet?

Tags: html, forms, local, export-to-excel

I'm making a html browser based logger for use by multiple users at my workplace.

I would like to be able to output data from forms (on this locally stored webpage) to an excel spreadsheet (also stored locally). This is not a page that will be hosted on the internet, only on the shared drive at work.

Is there any easy way to make the code below (for example) output to specific cells in an excel spreadaheet? Ideally every time a new form is submitted it will appear in the row below the last output on the spreadsheet.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form</title>

 <form>
First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
  

</head>

<body>



</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance for any responses!

Comment: Plain HTML **can't** do this on its own. You need something else - AFAIK I don't think Javascript is viable for this - you need a server-side language.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a server side language like PHP for example, read the data from the submitted form and write it as a csv file. Then you can open this file in excel.

Use [fgetcsv](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fgetcsv.asp) to read the file and then add your new data. Saving the new file is easy as well using [fputcsv](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fputcsv.asp)